# Anybody have/know of a delta star transform algorithm/code?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Do you guys know any delta star code/program. I would do it myself but I don't have enough time, and it would be a good way to let other people know your work.
Complex impedances pleas

Comment: If you're assuming balanced loads and generators, just multiply or divide by \$\sqrt 3\$.  I'm not sure I'm seeing the program-worthiness of this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic transformation that is documented e.g. in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform). See attached screenshot.

[image: SCREENSHOT FROM WIKIPEDIA]

Please, note also that it is written that you ca replace complex "objects" (impedance, admittance) to resistance terms.